# Symfony2 | Forms - Creating complex field-type and convert them to one field in the orm

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to create new form-field-type which include multiple inputs but it translated to combined data in my entity..

#### Entity

I want to save two fields in my event entity:

1. `location<spatial point>`
2. `gmap_data<json>`

#### Form

I needed to create 3 inputs who include the gmaps data.

### The Question

1. How can create form-field-type who have actually 3 inputs fields?
2. How can I create a DataTransformer which transform this 3 fields into entity requirment?(from the 3 input fields to the orm fields: geospatial-point and json)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for all of you who interesting in the solution:

1. Create 3 AbstractType:
   `myformType`
   `GmapType`
   `GeolocationType`
2. Create 2 transformers
   `GeolocationTransformer` - transform Point() to string
   `LocationTransformer` - transform gmap to geolocation string
3. Placing gmap and geolocation in `myformType`